# How can one generate a binary tree recursively?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

main class: binary tree

it contains the root node and a binary tree constructor

```
public class BinaryTree{
Node root;
BinaryTree (int depth){
    this.root = new Node(depth);
    root.generateTree(depth);
}
```

sub class node.

the generateTree() method is defined in this class but doesn't work.

the nodes represent the branches of the tree.

generateTree returns a binary tree.

```
class Node{
    final int LEAF = 1;
    final int BALL = 2;
    final int CANDLE = 3;
    int depth;
    int decoration;
    String color;
    boolean on;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node(int depth){
        this.depth = depth;
    }
    void setLeaf(){
        decoration = LEAF;
    }
    void setBall(String color){
        color = color;
    }
    void setCandle(boolean on){
        on = on;
    }
    BinaryTree generateTree(int depth) {
        if (depth == 0) {
            return root;
        }
        else if (depth > 1) {
            if (root.right == null){
                root.right = new Node(depth-1);
                root.left = new Node(depth-1);
            }
            for (int i=0; i < depth; i++){
                Node node = new Node(depth);
                node.right = new Node(depth-1);
                node.left = new Node(depth-1);
            }
        }
          generateTree(depth - 1);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than returning BinaryTree as the output, try having a method that returns just a node:

```
private static Node generateTree (int depth) {
    if (depth < 0) return null;
    Node currentNode = new Node(depth);
    if (depth > 0) {
        currentNode.left = generateTree(depth-1);
        currentNode.right = generateTree(depth-1);
    }
    return currentNode;
}
```

**EDIT**:

rather than calling the generateTree method as a function of the Node class, you should call the function and set its returned value in the constructor.

```
BinaryTree (int depth) {
    this.root = generateTree(depth);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the method needs to return a binary tree.

Comment: If that is the case, I'll update my post to explain how to do it.